# Use match geometry effect when navigating between views using a navigation link

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-animation, swiftui-transition

My home view contains a `CustomView` that opens a detailed view via a `NavigationLink` when tapped. The detailed view also contains the `CustomView`, just in a different location.

Can I use the match geometry effect to transition/animate the location of the `CustomView` when the navigation link is clicked?

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Top")
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView(namespace: namespace)
                } label: {
                    CustomView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
                }
                Text("Bottom")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct DetailView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomView()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
            Text("Details")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say, "no, you can't use [`.matchedGeometryEffect`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/matchedgeometryeffect(id:in:properties:anchor:issource:)) to animate the position of a view across a [NavigationStack](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/) transition."

Some details: first of all, the .matchedGeometryEffect will not work without an animation block. So you could rewrite your code to something like this:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    @State private var showDetail = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Top")
                Button {
                    withAnimation() {
                        showDetail.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    CustomView
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
                }
                Text("Bottom")
            }
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $showDetail) {
                DetailView(namespace: namespace)
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct DetailView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomView()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
            Text("Details")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

This gives you an opportunity to use [`withAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/withanimation(_:_:)) in a way that matchedGeometryEffect requires. However, you still don't get the animation you want, leading me to the conclusion above.

I would speculate that Navigation transitions are different from normal SwiftUI transitions. A clue supporting this is that any [.transition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/transition(_:)-5h5h0) you could apply to the things in DetailView do not trigger during transition. Another clue is that using `withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: 5))` does not give you a 5 second transition.

Your best bet might be to not use NavigationStack. Just use a conditional (with animated transition) to switch between the two layouts. I would also recommend you spend a few days studying the excellent resources on the [Swift UI Lab site](https://swiftui-lab.com/), with [this](https://swiftui-lab.com/matchedgeometryeffect-part1/) being a particularly relevant page for you.

I hope that helps!

Comment: what if we add animation modifier to matchedGeometryEffect?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific, please? I don't follow.

Answer (score 0):

Using the animation modifier can impact the performance, may not be the best solution, but still you can give it a try

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Top")
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailView(namespace: namespace)
                } label: {
                    CustomView()
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
                        .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
                }
                Text("Bottom")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            CustomView()
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "testId", in: namespace)
                .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
            Text("Details")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this does give the view an animation, it starts in a random place. Bottom right corner for the pushed view, the when popping the view it animated from the centre up to the corner and back again.

Comment: @Darren This may be happening because the match geometry effect relies on the stable names of views to accurately animate them